# Show another page when using blockUI plugin

Tags: php, ajax, get, blockui

I would like to get the content of a php file on the click event of an element while blocking the ui by using this plugin. My code is this:

```
<li onclick="$.blockUI({ message: $.get('page.php') });" />
```

this does block the UI, but nothing else happens. Does the jQuery get function return the contents of that file? Should I use another function for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking to do would be the following:

```
<li onclick="javascript:showMessage();"></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showMessage() {
    $.get('page.php', function(html) {
        $.blockUI({ message: html });
    });
}
</script>
```

Though if your `page.php` takes a moment or two to build, `blockUI` won't fire until it does.

Also, I've had mixed results with putting complex commands in an `onclick` or `href`, so I've found it more reliable to call a function.

Comment: I created a function as you say and now nothing happens. Blocking is not activated. I checked the page I am trying to load in a browser, the page url is localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/childoftwentytwelve/twitter/redirect.php. This page uses the header() function to redirect me to Twitter's sign in page. I am trying to make this appear in a box through this plugin.

Comment: When hitting the browser with this url, I do get redirected to Twitter's website.

Comment: Maybe blockUI is expecting some static HTML?

Comment: That is most likely.  I don't typically use blockUI for things like this.  You may want to look into something like jquery fancybox instead, as it supports static HTML, most javascript, and if necessary, iframes.

Comment: By 'most javascript', I mean fancybox does not trigger document.ready or onload, but you can make that work in other ways.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Tried the iFrame with a simplemodal plugin , so far no luck.